# How to use swift to convert direction degree to text?

Tags: swift, swift4

I got a oc version

```
public class Heading
{
    private string[] m_names[]=new string[8] { "N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW" };
    public string this[float angle]{get{return m_names[((int)((angle-22.5f)/45.0f))&7]}}
}
```

Then I convert to swift version

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {        
    let trueHeading = newHeading.trueHeading
    let angle = Double.pi / 180 * trueHeading

    let dir = [ "N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW" ]
    let dir2=dir[(((trueHeading-22.5)/45.0)) as Int & 7]
}
```

But it is not works, there is an error "Expected ',' separator" in this line

```
let dir2=dir[(((trueHeading-22.5)/45.0)) as Int & 7]
```

Comment: "I got a oc version" ... What is "oc"?

Comment: Side notes: 1)  According to docs `A negative value indicates that the heading could not be determined.` 2) `dir2` doesn't represent a real cardinal direction (e.g. trueHeading equal to 90 means device is pointed due east while it would be NE in your case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want either:

```
func compassDirection(for heading: CLLocationDirection) -> String? {
    if heading < 0 { return nil }

    let directions = ["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]
    let index = Int((heading + 22.5) / 45.0) & 7
    return directions[index]
}
```

Note, it's `+`, not `-`.

Or you can use `rounded` to avoid confusion about whether to add or subtract the 22.5:

```
let index = Int((heading / 45).rounded()) % 8
```

---

You can then use this `compassDirection` result like so:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    guard let direction = compassDirection(for: newHeading.trueHeading) else {
        // handle lack of heading here
        return
    }

    // you can use `direction` here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `let dir2=dir[Int((trueHeading - 22.5) / 45.0) & 7]`